# Nested Conditional (If-Else) inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

First time asking a question here. Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm mostly a front-end guy and sometimes get tripped up with the SQL syntax / control flow.

I have a stored procedure I've written that specifies a parameter (`@listAll`) to be passed in that specifies whether to list all registrations within a queue in a table for viewing.

I'd like to run the `RQ.Processed`, which shows as an `INT` (0 or 1), through an IF-ELSE condition to set the 0 or 1 to a string (Not Processed / Processed). This will be populating a data table on our front end for our customers to view a registration queue.

However, anywhere I try to add this condition I'm getting syntax errors. I'm also assuming the variable that will be used for the data type conversion (`@statusConversion`) needs to be outside the scope of the select statements, but I may be totally off.

Here is what I have so far:

```
create proc [dbo].[Portal.RegistrationQueue_ListAll] 
    (@listAll int)
as
    set nocount on

    declare @statusConversion varchar(30)

    if (@listAll = 1)
    begin
        select 
            C.CompanyName as 'Company', 
            RCG.Learner_Tag as 'Registration Group', 
            convert(varchar(40), RQ.CreatedOn, 110) as 'Date', 
            RQ.Processed as 'Status'
        from 
            [dbo].[Portal.RegistrationQueue] RQ
        join 
            [dbo].[Portal.Company] C on RQ.CompanyID = C.Id
        join 
            [dbo].[Portal.RegisteredCourseGroup] RCG on RQ.RegistrationGroupID = RCG.Id
    end
    else
    begin
        select 
            C.CompanyName as 'Company', 
            RCG.Learner_Tag as 'Registration Group', 
            convert(varchar(40), RQ.CreatedOn, 110) as 'Date', 
            RQ.Processed as 'Status'
        from 
            [dbo].[Portal.RegistrationQueue] RQ
        join 
            [dbo].[Portal.Company] C on RQ.CompanyID = C.Id
        join 
            [dbo].[Portal.RegisteredCourseGroup] RCG on RQ.RegistrationGroupID = RCG.Id
        where 
            RQ.Processed = 0
    end
GO
```

What I need is help on where to place the IF-ELSE to convert the (0,1) to 'Not Processed', 'Processed' and also if I've placed that conversion variable in the right place.

Thanks.

Comment: If the problem is the variable. Try create a smaller sample so you can test it more easy, and easy for us to help you. [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use a case statement rather than a variable.  Your select statements within the procedure would then look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    C.CompanyName AS [Company], 
    RCG.Learner_Tag as [Registration Group], 
    convert(varchar(40), RQ.CreatedOn, 110) as [Date], 
    CASE WHEN RQ.Processed = 1 THEN 'Processed' ELSE 'Not Processed' END AS [Status] --this will display the text description for status
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you, morgb.  this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Since the OP specified that the value is an `INT`, a good practice would be to explicitly handle the expected values and use the default `ELSE` clause to handle unexpected values, e.g. `case RQ.Processed when 0 then 'Not Processed' when 1 then 'Processed' else Cast( RQ.Processed as VarChar(10) ) end`. (Although Microsoft can't figure it out, it is a `CASE` _expression_, not _statement_.)

Comment: Thank you for that addition, HABO.  I may implement that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as a column in the returned set:

```
case RQ.Processed
  when 1 then 'Processed'
  else 'Not Processed'
end  as Status
```

When RQ.Processed equals 1, this returns "Not Processed", and when it equals anything else--including NULL--it returns "Not Procesed".

Similarly, and as a side-note, you could drop the IF/ELSE and duplciated query using a `where` claused like this:

```
when RQ.Processed = case @listAll
                      when 1 then RQ.Processed
                      else 0
                    end
```

Comment: Thank you, Philip.  I will try this as well.